# Why is my location null? - Android

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps-v2

Why is the value of my location variable null?  I'm setting up my LocationManager correctly.

Here is my source code:

```
    //Get the current location
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myCriteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(myCriteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); 
    //Location location;

    if (isGpsEnabled) { 
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else { 
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Provider is: "+provider);
    Log.i(TAG, "Location is: "+location);
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
06-17 10:40:52.637: D/dalvikvm(15106): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 534K, 7% free 10586K/11360K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-17 10:40:52.677: I/OGT.RideTracking(15106): Provider is: gps
06-17 10:40:52.677: I/OGT.RideTracking(15106): Location is: null
06-17 10:40:52.677: D/AndroidRuntime(15106): Shutting down VM
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException - Location - getLatitude() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150066/nullpointerexception-location-getlatitude-method)

Comment: there is no warranty that `getLastKnownLocation`gives you a location. If it is `null`you should call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` and wait the provider gets the location.

Comment: Do you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions set?

Comment: Yes I do have those permissions in the Manifest file

Comment: you are probably getting null because there is currently no lastKnownLocation. Open up google maps or something that uses GPS and it will probably work

Comment: I've been running it on a tablet and the error I get above is the one I get.

Comment: Look at "Location Strategies" in the Android Development site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Hello user268397 `[android-maps-extensions]` tag is meant for [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) library. I have removed unnecessary tag from your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

These variable are class variables

```
LocationManager locManager;
LocationListener locListener;
```

Add this code on `create` method

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
```

In the same file add this code

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d("tag", "Finding Latitude");
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        Log.d("tag", "Lat: " + String.valueOf(lat));
        Log.d("tag", "Finding Longitude");
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();
        Log.d("tag", "Lon: " + String.valueOf(lon));
        Log.i(Tag, loc.toString());
        String Text = "Lat: " + lat + "\nLon: " + lon;

        // Display location
        locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** Requires

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// getting GPS status
isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Check if gps is enabled.

Comment: But you call Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); without checking if gps is enabled.