# other way to get current location in Android

Tags: android, geolocation

the code below gives a `NullPointerException` is there any other way of getting current location in Android application

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

};

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


double latitude = location.getLatitude(); //NullPointerException
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the bug instead of trying to find a different way?

Answer (score 0):

sure you could use the google play services location API:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

but maybe you should look into your problem first... see this question for your null problem:
[android getlastknownlocation returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689372/android-getlastknownlocation-returns-null)